# C# calling code from file

Tags: c#, file

Is it possible to call my c# code from a file? The application should be able to scan through the lines in my file and execute the code inside.

Suppose I have the following method in my application:

```
public void ShowMsg(String msg) 
{
     MessageBox.Show(msg);
}
```

and the line `ShowMsg("Hello")` in my file.

I want my application to be able to read the code from file and in the end it should display a message box with the string "Hello". But of course what I'm trying to achieve is way more complicated than simply displaying a message box to the user.

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118077/using-javascript-for-custom-purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a tutorial on [`compiling and executing code at run-time`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9019/Compiling-and-Executing-Code-at-Runtime). It should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, there is an API for it actually.

So here is a link to how you would do it, straight from stackoverflow:
[Is it possible to dynamically compile and execute C# code fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

sample source in code project:
[Compiling code during runtime](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10324/Compiling-code-during-runtime)