# scripting with c# desktop application

Tags: c#, javascript, wsh

I have a C#  desktop application which supports new C# plugins.

I want to change existing C# application capable of accepting scripts as plugin.

Scripts may be a JavaScript,Windows script Host (WSh) or any script. (It must be a plugin and want to compile and run at run-time)

I want to know whether C# has script compile and run functionality. If you know any supporting dll, good links or helpfull projects, please let me know.

Comment: Have a look at http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/ - using V8 will certainly be more comfortable for experienced JS developers than the WSH JScript implementation.

Comment: [Using javascript for custom purposes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118077/using-javascript-for-custom-purposes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found http://jint.codeplex.com/ useful for javascript solution with C# desktop application, minimum level interaction like javascript to C# and C# javascript succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

From the [CS-Script homepage](http://www.csscript.net/):

> "CS-Script is a CLR (Common Language Runtime) based scripting system which uses ECMA-compliant C# as a programming language. CS-Script currently targets Microsoft implementation of CLR (.NET 2.0/3.0/3.5/4.0) with full support on Mono."

Plus, it's open source too!

Another option would be to implement [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Dynamic Language Runtime](http://dlr.codeplex.com/), which allows you to embed languages like [IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/)
and [IronRuby](http://ironruby.codeplex.com/) in your program.

Here is a [webpage](http://secretgeek.net/host_ironpython.asp) about how to embed IronPython in a C# program.

See also [Embedding the DLR](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/embedding.shtml) on Voidspace

Answer (score 0):

C# doesn't have inbuilt compilers for JavaScript or any other script, You have to attach your own compiler with your application and invoke that at runtime.