# call back to C# function from within VBScript run with msscript.ocx

Tags: c#, vbscript, controls, msscriptcontrol

I want to use msscript.ocx to call VBScript from C#, and allow the VBScript code to call back to functions in the C# program.

For example, in the following VBScript code, `Clicktext` is a custom C# function in the same clsss that is using msscript.ocx to run the VBScript.

```
For i=0 to i=4

    Clicktext("Auto")

Next
```

The Clicktext function shoud be called 5 times.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118077/using-javascript-for-custom-purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ComVisible console application with a reference to Interop.MSScriptControl:

```
// !! http://sandsprite.com/blogs/index.php?uid=11&pid=83

using System;
using MSScriptControl;

//class test has to support IDispatch to AddObject(). So make the assembly ComVisible
//via AssemblyInfo.cs or [assembly: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]

namespace MsScTest {
    public class CsHelper {
        public int increment(int y) { return ++y; }
    }

    class Program {
        public static MSScriptControl.ScriptControl sc = new ScriptControl();
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            sc.Language = "VBScript";
            sc.AddObject("CsHelper", new CsHelper(), true);
            sc.AddCode(@"
Function inc(n)
  inc = CsHelper.increment(n)
End Function
MsgBox inc(4711), 0, 'With a little help from my friend CsHelper'
".Replace("'", "\""));
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

pudding:

```
---------------------------
With a little help from my friend CsHelper
---------------------------
4712
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

demonstrates how to call a method of a C# object from VBScript code added to a MSScriptControl.

Comment: Thanks a lot Horner!! The solution provided by you worked for me.

Comment: Just one big notice: adding derived classes as script Object's may end up as major screwup. I was adding class derived from Form. And method on that class was never called. As soon I removed ": Form" code started working.
PS: above code helped me locate this problem, so +1 ;)