# Marshal a C# struct to C++ VARIANT

Tags: c#, c++, com, marshalling

To start with, I'm not very familiar with the COM-technology, this is the first time I'm working with it so bear with me.
I'm trying to call a COM-object function from C#.

This is the interface in the idl-file:

```
[id(6), helpstring("vConnectInfo=ConnectInfoType")] 
HRESULT ConnectTarget([in,out] VARIANT* vConnectInfo);
```

This is the interop interface I got after running tlbimp:

```
    void ConnectTarget(ref object vConnectInfo);
```

The c++ code in COM object for the target function:

```
STDMETHODIMP PCommunication::ConnectTarget(VARIANT* vConnectInfo)
{
    if (!((vConnectInfo->vt & VT_ARRAY) && (vConnectInfo->vt & VT_BYREF)))
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    ConnectInfoType *pConnectInfo = (ConnectInfoType *)((*vConnectInfo->pparray)->pvData);
...
}
```

This COM-object is running in another process, it is not in a dll.

I can add that the COM object is also used from another program written in C++. In that case there is no problem because in C++ a VARIANT is created and pparray->pvData is set to the connInfo data-structure and then the COM-object is called with the VARIANT as parameter.

In C#, as I understand, my struct should be marshalled as a VARIANT automatically.

These are two methods I've been using (or actually I've tried a lot more...) to call this method from C#:

```
    private void method1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pcom.PCom PCom = new pcom.PCom();
        pcom.IGeneralManagementServices mgmt = (pcom.IGeneralManagementServices)PCom;
        m_ci = new ConnectInfoType();
        fillConnInfo(ref m_ci);
        mgmt.ConnectTarget(m_ci);
    }
```

In the above case the struct gets marshalled as VT_UNKNOWN. This is a simple case and works if the parameter is not a struct (eg. works for int).

```
    private void method4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ConnectInfoType ci = new ConnectInfoType();
        fillConnInfo(ref ci);

        pcom PCom = new pcom.PCom();
        pcom.IGeneralManagementServices mgmt = (pcom.IGeneralManagementServices)PCom;

        ParameterModifier[] pms = new ParameterModifier[1];
        ParameterModifier pm = new ParameterModifier(1);
        pm[0] = true;
        pms[0] = pm;
        object[] param = new object[1];
        param[0] = ci;
        object[] args = new object[1];
        args[0] = param;
        mgmt.GetType().InvokeMember("ConnectTarget", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, mgmt, args, pms, null, null);
    }
```

In this case it gets marshalled as VT_ARRAY | VT_BYREF | VT_VARIANT. The problem is that when debugging the "target-function" ConnectTarget I cannot find the data I send in the SAFEARRAY-struct (or in any other place in memory either)

What do I do with a VT_VARIANT?

Any ideas on how to get my struct-data?

*Update:*

The ConnectInfoType struct:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class ConnectInfoType
    {
        public short network;
        public short nodeNumber;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 51)]
        public string connTargPassWord;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 8)]
        public string sConnectId;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
        public string sConnectPassword;
        public EnuConnectType eConnectType;
        public int hConnectHandle;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 8)]
        public string sAccessPassword;
    };
```

And the corresponding struct in c++:

```
typedef struct ConnectInfoType
{
    short network;
    short nodeNumber;
    char connTargPassWord[51];
    char sConnectId[8];
    char sConnectPassword[16];
    EnuConnectType eConnectType;
    int hConnectHandle;
    char sAccessPassword[8];
} ConnectInfoType;
```

Comment: Did you [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+COM+variant&oq=c%23+COM+variant&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j0l4.4373j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)? Looks like a few things that might help.

Comment: I've been searching all day, pretty much everything in the post is from searches. And search continues, thank you.

Comment: @jortan, it isn't clear, is your goal to pass an array of `ConnectInfoType` from C# to C++, or just a single `ConnectInfoType`?

Comment: @Noseratio, it is a single ConnectionInfoType.

Comment: @jortan, why can't you just pass a struct, e.g. like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18435743/1768303

Comment: @Noseratio, would be great but does not work. My struct gets marshaled as VT_UNKNOWN. I'm using the interface I was given by tlbimp.exe, would it be better to create the interface manually and use MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct) on the parameter?

Comment: It looks like whoever coded the C++ part may have gotten it wrong. Do you have control over the unmanaged side sources? Check this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/122289

Comment: @Noseratio, I've updated the post a lot. The COM object is in its own process, not in a dll. I have the source for the C++ COM but it is also used by other applications, thats why I rather not change it. But can do if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an acceptable solution/workaround. I convert the struct to a byte array and then cast the received data to the ConnectInfoType struct.

```
    // C#
    private void method3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pcom.PCom PCom = new pcom.PCom();
        pcom.IGeneralManagementServices mgmt = (pcom.IGeneralManagementServices)PCom;
        ConnectInfoType ci = new ConnectInfoType();
        fillConnInfo(ref ci);

        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(ci));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(ci, ptr, false);
        byte[] arr = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(ci)];
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(ci));

        mgmt.ConnectTarget(arr);
    }
```

This will be marshalled as `VT_ARRAY |VT_UI1` so I've changed the c++ code to:

```
// C++
STDMETHODIMP PCommunication::ConnectTarget(VARIANT* vConnectInfo)
{
    if (!((vConnectInfo->vt & VT_ARRAY) && (vConnectInfo->vt & VT_UI1)))
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    ConnectInfoType *pConnectInfo = (ConnectInfoType *)(vConnectInfo->parray->pvData);
...
}
```

If anyone know a better solution, feel free to add it.

Comment: What you did is a recommended solution for out-of-proc servers, as described in the MSKB article I mentioned: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/122289. There doesn't seem to be a better way of doing this, without changing the C++ part significantly. However, you should be freeing the allocated memory (`Marshal.FreeHGlobal`) after the `Marshal.Copy` call, and make a copy of `ConnectInfoType` on the C++ side, instead of storing a pointer to it (not clear if you're doing so already).

Answer (score 0):

Use this class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.variantwrapper%28v=vs.110%29.aspx to wrapp it and then call the desired method.

Can you post the c++ source of the Type "ConnectInfoType"?

Comment: If do this and call the COM-function with "method1" in my post I get an exception "VariantWrappers cannot be stored in Variants.". If I do it with "method4" it will be marshaled as VT_UNKNOWN.

Comment: Try to add a [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4/SysUInt)] to the enum variable within your c# struct enum type